# server error 500 when i tried to re-enable an app

Tags: google-app-engine

I've disabled an app from Google's app engine Administration - Application Settings.
Now I trid to re-enble it. But the brower returns a server error (500).
I trid to request permanenant deletion. Again the same server error occurs.

How should I proceed?

Thanks.

Things became worse. I tried to create another APP and get it running. when everything seems OK, I disabled it and tried to delete or re-enable it. The same errors occured. 
Anything to try now?

Thanks

Comment: Did the request permanent deletion work, or is it still showing in Administratio?

Comment: No, it did not. The request was not accepted by the server. On the manage disable app page, it did not show the app will be deleted in XX hours.